# Please tell me why $s/S < λ/d$ for interference to happen in Young's Double Slit Experiment?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, interference

The question was 
what is the effect on the interference fringes in Young's experiment when we bring source slit closer to the double slit plane and its answer is given as: 
https://photos.app.goo.gl/3i9iWZqFVp3g72RA9

Comment: Use of private cloud is unacceptable on SE due to risk of link rot.

Comment: this site and the links it has may help you http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/slits.html#c2